# Why only Right gesture showing?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I've never used gestures before, and wrote this bit of code (Note: I am using Xamarin and iOS).

When I use the code below, the only value ever received is "Right", despite what I do in the simulator or on my actual iPhone. I'm stumped as to why. I figure I should either get nothing, or everything should work.

```
// Swipe gesture
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(sw => 
  {
      if (sw.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left) {
        txtTestLabel.Text = "Left";
      }
      else if (sw.Direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right) {
            txtTestLabel.Text = "Right";
      }
      else {
        txtTestLabel.Text = sw.Direction.ToString();
      }
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default direction of the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is right (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). Set the `direction` property to left to track the left swipe.

Comment: Note from the other Krumelur: even though it is a bit mask, you cannot detect in the handler which direction was used. So if that is important, you will need to use two different gesture recognizers; one for left and one for right.

Comment: @Krumelur (other): You are right, I remembered wrong. Two recognizers is the way to go, sorry about the previously misleading sentence.